# oracle forms it shows only prompts not shows item fields in the canvas

Tags: forms, oracleforms

I add sub class information to blocks , items and buttons. When i ran the form in application it shows only prompts not shows item fields

can any one suggest what is happen here

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Little bit hard to say without more information but most likely the forms compiler is not able to find your object library. Please make sure that the object library is in the forms path.